# scope.modal.show() is not a function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I try to open a modal view. For that i use the following:

```
crop: function(options) {
  options = this.initOptions(options);

  var scope = $rootScope.$new(true);

  ionic.extend(scope, options);

  scope.modal = $ionicModal.fromTemplate(template, {
    scope: scope
  });

  // Show modal and initialize cropper.
  return scope.modal.show().then(function() {
    return (new jrCropController(scope)).promise.promise;
  });
},
```

This is working fine. But now i dont want to define my template inside the javascript. I want to define my template in an extra html file and so i did.

So i had to replace this:

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplate(template,
```

with this:

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(url,
```

But now i get the following error:

```
ionic.bundle.js:20306 TypeError: scope.modal.show is not a function
at Object.crop (jr-crop.js:287)
at Scope.$scope.crop (polaroids_edit.js:51)
at $parseFunctionCall (ionic.bundle.js:21044)
at ionic.bundle.js:53458
at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:23100)
at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:23199)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:53457)
at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:11713)
at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2863)
at tapClick (ionic.bundle.js:2852)
```

Why do i get this error when i use a template url instead of a template? For me that makes no sense since it is the same method in both cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you're missing the fact that the `fromTemplate()` returns the modal object while `fromTemplateUrl()` returns a promise, since you're loading the template asynchronously.

Thus, this works fine

```
scope.modal = $ionicModal.fromTemplate(template, {
    scope: scope
});
```

while this will **not** work

```
scope.modal = $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(url, {
    scope: scope
});
```

since `scope.modal` will be a promise object.

You will have to wait for the promise to resolve and then assign the modal, like

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(url, {
    scope: $scope,
}).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
});
```

For reference check out [$ionicModal: fromTemplate vs. fromTemplateUrl functions](https://gist.github.com/videde/d305a084e538feacdb96)

Comment: Oh yes you are right. Thx for the explanation and the solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
crop: function(options) {
  options = this.initOptions(options);

  var scope = $rootScope.$new(true);

  ionic.extend(scope, options);

  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(template, {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    scope.modal = modal;
    return scope.modal.show().then(function() {
      return (new jrCropController(scope)).promise.promise;
    });
  });
}
```

[Iconic modal](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/)